# Blender 2.8: My 2.79 creations have no textures!

Tags: texturing

I created a model using v2.79b including textures, but when I "upgraded" to 2.8 and loaded my project, all of my textures were gone!

The entire interface has changed so much they *really* should have called it "Blender 3.0". Just figuring out how to switch to "Texture View" required some Googling. And since my textures *still* don't show, I'm not 100% sure I'm even doing it right, but when I check the Collection Tree, I find there are no textures linked to any of my materials!

The whole damn interface has changed so much simply reapplying all of my textures is going to be a PIA... unless I'm simply missing something.

Am I wrong or does v2.8 ignore linked textures assigned using earlier versions of the program? :(

Comment: This may an issue of just putting the textures back as when I " Upgraded to blender 2.8" most of my textures stayed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "putting the textures back". They're are in the same location as before. I did not move any files.

Comment: By that I mean are the textures still connected in the node editor are they still connected are they layed out correctly.